# Reboots on SoC mt7621a and kernel 5.0.19-rt10

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, mutex, spinlock

I'm currently working on the development of a product with se MT7621A SoC and with kernel 5.0.19.rt10.

I'm having rebooting problems and in order to debug it, I activated some kernel options as `Detect soft lockups` and `Detect hung tasks`. I've obtained different stack traces just before rebooting. These stack traces are different but all of them finish on the function `task_blocks_on_rt_mutex()`

Here is an example:

```
[ 2370.270000] 000: Kernel bug detected[#1]:
[ 2370.270000] 000: CPU: 0 PID: 799 Comm: agsPoll0 Tainted: G           O      5.0.19-rt10 #5
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 0   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 4   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $ 8   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000001
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ffffffff
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $12   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00014b40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $16   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda5be0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $20   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $24   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80010580
[ 2370.270000] 000:          
[ 2370.270000] 000:          
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: $28   :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e722000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bca8
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80720000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8007a2a0
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Hi    : 000227df
[ 2370.270000] 000: Lo    : 19f38000
[ 2370.270000] 000: epc   : 8007a2c0 task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x6c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: ra    : 8007a2a0 task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x4c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: Status: 11000402
[ 2370.270000] 000: KERNEL 
[ 2370.270000] 000: EXL 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Cause : 50800034 (ExcCode 0d)
[ 2370.270000] 000: PrId  : 0001992f (MIPS 1004Kc)
[ 2370.270000] 000: Modules linked in:
[ 2370.270000] 000:  prd_phy_controller(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  csl_mng_module(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  csl_packet_module(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  mac(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  alb_critical_lock(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  phyif(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ttstools(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  gpio_bb(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  loopprotect(O)

[ 2370.270000] 000:  sys_mng(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  alb_workqueues(O)
[ 2370.270000] 000:  iptable_filter
[ 2370.270000] 000:  [last unloaded: nf_nat]
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Process agsPoll0 (pid: 799, threadinfo=ef6213bf, task=9369b08c, tls=00000000)
[ 2370.270000] 000: Stack :
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8100df20
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80055d30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda608c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80723c40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805ed164
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda6e40
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fda72ec
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805eb030
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000009
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805ed1e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002a60
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e520
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8071e6e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  80720000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  805eb2bc
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000003
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8f4f0c40
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000:  81002f20
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd30
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc3c9e0
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000009
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc0bd3c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8fc3ce2c
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000:        
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ...
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Call Trace:
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007a2c0>] task_blocks_on_rt_mutex+0x6c/0x300
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb030>] rt_spin_lock_slowlock_locked+0xbc/0x2fc
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb2bc>] rt_spin_lock_slowlock+0x4c/0x70
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed430>] rt_spin_lock+0x68/0x78
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800149c8>] mips_cm_lock_other+0x13c/0x1e8
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800104b0>] mips_smp_send_ipi_mask+0x13c/0x20c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80055cf8>] check_preempt_curr+0x98/0xb4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80055d30>] ttwu_do_wakeup.isra.93+0x1c/0x110
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80056814>] try_to_wake_up+0x20c/0x46c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800806b0>] __handle_irq_event_percpu+0x7c/0x178
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800807dc>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x30/0x78
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8008087c>] handle_irq_event+0x58/0xb0
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800855e0>] handle_level_irq+0x10c/0x1f0
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007fc20>] generic_handle_irq+0x40/0x58
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8031c980>] gic_handle_shared_int+0xcc/0x19c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8007fc20>] generic_handle_irq+0x40/0x58
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed8b0>] do_IRQ+0x18/0x24
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8031baf8>] plat_irq_dispatch+0x90/0x110
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<80006ca8>] except_vec_vi_end+0xb8/0xc4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805ed08c>] _raw_spin_unlock_irq+0x18/0x4c
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eae60>] __rt_mutex_slowlock+0x110/0x224
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb378>] rt_mutex_slowlock_locked+0x98/0x284
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb5cc>] rt_mutex_slowlock.constprop.25+0x68/0xc4
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<805eb790>] __rt_mutex_lock_state+0x90/0xbc
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<c074d938>] AGSPollLoopStats+0xa0/0x10c [mac]
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8004d020>] kthread_worker_fn+0xc8/0x140
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<8004cee0>] kthread+0x118/0x148
[ 2370.270000] 000: [<800067ac>] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x14/0x1c
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: Code:
[ 2370.270000] 000:  00000000 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  2c420003 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  38420001 
[ 2370.270000] 000: <00020336>
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae710018 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae72001c 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e220038 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  ae620024 
[ 2370.270000] 000:  8e220160 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.270000] 000: 
[ 2370.830000] 000: ---[ end trace 0000000000000002 ]---
[ 2370.840000] 000: Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[ 2370.840000] 000: Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

I enabled the Lock debugging options in the kernel, but it always gets stucked on some kernel  code talking about deadlocks that I can't debug.

Any suggestions in order to proceed with the reboot debugging?